# Compiling mongoose for 32 BIT

Tags: c, ld

I had modified make file as

```
linux:
    $(CC) mongoose.c -shared -fPIC -fpic -m32  -o  $(LIB) $(LINFLAGS)
    $(CC) mongoose.c main.c -m32 -o $(PROG) $(LINFLAGS)
```

But when I run ld on mongoose I gets. I am getting warning that it is incompatible with i386

```
ld mongoose
ld: warning: i386 architecture of input file `mongoose' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ld is trying to create an x86-64 executable from your x86-32 object files, and is unhappy because that isn't something that makes sense. Use GCC to link instead of ld, passing the -m32 at link as well, and it will call the linker with the correct flags for linking x86-32 binaries.